# Linear approximation to the infinite product $\prod_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} (1+x^{1/p^k})$

Tags: numerical-methods, regression, recursion, infinite-product, linear-regression

Let's consider the function defined by the infinite product:

$$f_p(x)=\prod_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} (1+x^{1/p^k})$$

$$p \geq 2$$

The only closed form I know is for $p=2$.

$$f_2(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{2 \ln x}$$

However, numerically, it turns out that this function is very close to linear, and the larger $p$, the better the approximation.

For my purposes, it's enough to consider:

$$0 \leq x \leq 1$$

For small $x$ and small $p$ the linear approximation doesn't fit. See for $p=3$:

[image]

However, for $p=15$ linear approximation fits much better:

[image]

Thus, my question is:

> Can we obtain a highly accurate linear approximation $f_p(x)=A_p x+B_p$ without numerically computing the product for several points and using regression (i.e. least squares)?

Also, how can we prove that:

> $$\lim_{p \to \infty} f_p(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+x)$$

---

Motivation:

If we introduce a sequence:

$$a_{n+1}^p=a_n \frac{(a_n+b_n)^{p-1}}{2^{p-1}},\qquad b_{n+1}^p=b_n \frac{(a_n+b_n)^{p-1}}{2^{p-1}}$$

$$a_0>b_0, \qquad x=\frac{b_0}{a_0}$$

Then:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=(f_p(x))^{\frac{p-1}{p}} a_0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x \to 1$, $p \to \infty$ or $k \to \infty$, I think the following are right

$$ \begin{align}
x^{1/p^k} &= \exp( p^{-k} \log x) 
\\&= \exp\left( p^{-k} (x-1) + O(p^{-k} (x-1)^2 ) \right)
\\&= 1 + p^{-k} (x-1) + O\left(p^{-k} (x-1)^2 \right) 
\end{align}$$

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + x^{1/p^k} \right) = 1 + \frac{x-1}{2p^k} + O(p^{-k} (x-1)^2) $$

$$\begin{align}
 \log \prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + x^{1/p^k} \right)
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{2p^k} + O\left(p^{-k}(x-1)^2 \right)
\\&= \frac{p(x-1)}{2(p - 1)} + O((x-1)^2)
\end{align}$$

$$ \prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + x^{1/p^k} \right)
= 1 + \frac{p(x-1)}{2(p-1)} + O((x-1)^2)
$$

Comment: So for $p=3$ we will get: $$f_3(x) \approx 0.25+0.75 x$$ That's close enough to the approximation I've got with least squares, even though not very accurate. Thank you! Also proves the limit